# Unicode error - opening *.txt files with python

Tags: python, python-3.3

When I try to read a text file like so in python:

```
x = open("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Hi.txt", 'r')
```

This error is returned:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I looked around and found this question: ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file). Apparently I need to duplicate all of the backslashes so Unicode doesn't get all screwed up by what I am trying to do. So I did, but then when I ran print(x) I got this output:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\Hi.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

What on earth is this, and how do I fix it? I am running python 3.3, doing all of this in IDLE. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use raw strings with Windows-style filenames:

```
x = open(r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Hi.txt", 'r')
             ^^
```

Otherwise, Python's string engine thinks that `\U` is the start of a Unicode escape sequence - which of course it isn't in this case.

Then, you can't simply `print()` a file like this, you need to `read()` it first:

```
print(x.read())
```