# Trying to make a shortcut through python

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

Python 2.7

```
from Tkinter import *
import os

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.b = Button(self.frame, text = 'Open', command = self.openFile)
        self.b.grid(row = 1)
        self.frame.grid()
    def openFile(self):
        os.startfile("C:\Users\David\Desktop\minecraft.jar")

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

using py2exe it shows this error and its not compiling:
SyntaxError:  'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position
2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: related: [“Unicode Error ”unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes… Cannot open text files in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1347791/4279)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `\` in the following string literal. Otherwise, it is recognized as unicode escape sequence.

```
>>> "C:\Users\David\Desktop\minecraft.jar"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Explicitly escape them:

```
>>> "C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\minecraft.jar"
'C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\minecraft.jar'
```

or use raw string literals:

```
>>> r"C:\Users\David\Desktop\minecraft.jar"
'C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\minecraft.jar'
```

BTW, Python 2.x does not raise the SyntaxError for the string literal `"C:\Use..."` (unless you use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`). Check if you're using Python 3.x when using py2exe.