# How to encode Python 3 string using \u escape code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, unicode-escapes

In Python 3, suppose I have

```
>>> thai_string = 'สีเ'
```

Using `encode` gives

```
>>> thai_string.encode('utf-8')
b'\xe0\xb8\xaa\xe0\xb8\xb5'
```

My question: how can I get `encode()` to return a `bytes` sequence using `\u` instead of `\x`?  And how can I `decode` them back to a Python 3 `str` type?

I tried using the `ascii` builtin, which gives

```
>>> ascii(thai_string)
"'\\u0e2a\\u0e35'"
```

But this doesn't seem quite right, as I can't decode it back to obtain `thai_string`.

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) tells me that

- `\xhh` escapes the character with the hex value `hh` while
- `\uxxxx` escapes the character with the 16-bit hex value `xxxx`

The documentation says that `\u` is only used in string literals, but I'm not sure what that means.  Is this a hint that my question has a flawed premise?

Comment: What about `.decode('utf-8')`? Aren't strings in Python unicode anyway?

Comment: @Zizouz212, neither `thai_string` nor `ascii(thai_string)` have a `decode` method, and `thai_string.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')` brings me back to where I started, `thai_string`, which is not the desired output.

Comment: Python documentation relevant to the escape sequence `\u`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1347791/1959808

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to work with surrogate pairs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147259/how-to-work-with-surrogate-pairs-in-python)

Comment: I also use `ascii(sku).replace(r"\x", r"\u00")` and works better

Comment: @FelipeBuccioni That code corrupts strings that contain a backslash followed by a literal x.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `unicode_escape`:

```
>>> thai_string.encode('unicode_escape')
b'\\u0e2a\\u0e35\\u0e40'
```

Note that `encode()` will always return a byte string (bytes) and the `unicode_escape` encoding [is intended to](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

> Produce a string that is suitable as Unicode literal in Python source code

Comment: Perfect. But why does this string have two slashes before the "u" while the "x" only has one?

Comment: This is simply how Python displays a literal backslash inside a quoted string. Compare `'\\n'` (literal backslash, literal `n`) to `'\n'` (newline character).

Comment: If you want the result as a string, you can tack on `.decode('ascii')`