# How to represent Unicode encoded strings in Python?

Tags: java, python, string

I am translating a program from Java to Python.

In the source code of the Java program, the strings use the "\u000x" encoding for a few characters. As I understand, this is the unicode representation of the character and x is a hexadecimal code for that character.

In Java program the string is declared as:

```
data = "~\\GJ_F^A\u001eXJ]NK\u0018!"
```

How do I represent this in Python?

The above string has two encoded characters:

```
\u001e
\u0018
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encode Python 3 string using \u escape code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280753/how-to-encode-python-3-string-using-u-escape-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Python also has Unicode escape codes.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support) This is valid python:

```
data = "~\\GJ_F^A\u001eXJ]NK\u0018!"
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for confirming. The issue in my case was that I was using Python 2.x version which did not have support for such encoding. I used Python 3.x and it worked properly.

Comment: good choice, not a good idea to do new projects in python2 - but you can use unicode escapes in unicode strings in python2 too https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code