# Python3 - replacing non ascii characters to their unicode representative value?

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding

lets say i have a string,
`"Hello–World"`

how would I convert it to something like this
`"Hello\u2013World"`
where `"\u2013"` is the unicode representative of `"–"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.encode` with `unicode_escape`:

```
>>> print(s.encode('unicode_escape'))
b'Hello\\u2013World'
```

If you want a string (and to a byte string like above):

```
>>> print(s.encode('unicode_escape').decode())
Hello\u2013World
```

Comment: thanks, didn't know that encoding method exists

Comment: More encodings here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings

Comment: I think it would be better to delete this answer, because it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32280815 and fixes would have to be made to both. If you don't delete it, it should mention that this encoding also produces other Python escape sequences like `\t` and `\xXX`.