# Find the default local Jupyter directory

Tags: python, jupyter

I need the location of jupyter's local directory to use in another script.  For example, when starting jupyter, the console prints:

```
> Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\PC\Documents
```

Somehow, jupyter has set this path as the default local location from which my notebooks are served.  It is the "root" of my jupyter environment.  How do I find this default setting?  Is there a pre-existing file I can parse, or a command I can type?

---

Among other attempts, I've tried the following:

```
> jupyter notebook --help-all
--NotebookApp.notebook_dir=<Unicode>
    Default: ''
    The directory to use for notebooks and kernels.
```

Note: I do not have a config file, nor do I not wish to [generate a config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252884/jupyter-notebook-starting-directory) to get this information.  For clarity, I am not concerned with [changing the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680463/change-ipython-jupyter-notebook-working-directory).

Comment: How are you starting Jupyter? Is the path `C:\Users\PC\Documents` constant or does it differ?

Comment: @JacobBudin I start jupyter using Anaconda's JupyterNotebook link, thus yes it is always a reproducible start.  However, it appears to run `jupyter-notebook-script.py` which calls `notebook.notebookapp`.  There may be code there for parsing the local directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/37690452, it seems that the default location is set/derived in the `cwp.py` file in the Anaconda folder. For default installs on Windows, it seems that this script would be at (for username `PC`, as in your question) `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\cwp.py`.

Finding the source of cwp.py on [github.com/ContinuumIO/menuinst](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/menuinst/blob/ba534f8912b5d2dc82915f99d0ca27273c8b710b/cwp.py), it seems that it's basically using the current Windows User's Documents folder.

**edit:**

I reproduce below the gist of my post on the github issue at [notebook/issues/2941#issuecomment-337076059](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2941#issuecomment-337076059) as requested in comments:

---

Unless specified otherwise in config or environment variables, the notebook server will use the current working directory *at start time* as the notebook directory. Yours seems to be set to the documents folder because the Anaconda shortcut which you're using to start the notebook is doing a little magic to set the working directory before starting the notebook server. For you purposes, you could:

1. Explicitly set the notebook directory in a config file or environment variable
2. Assume the notebook root is at

   ```
   os.path.expanduser('~/Documents')
   ```

   (note this may <del>not work</del> require adjustment if OS language is not English)
3. Use the pip/conda package [`menuinst`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/menuinst/) to find the folder, replicating the same logic as the anaconda shortcut exactly - something along the lines of:

   ```py
   from menuinst.windows.knownfolders import FOLDERID, get_folder_path

   documents_folder, exception = get_folder_path(FOLDERID.Documents)
   if exception:
       documents_folder, exception = get_folder_path(FOLDERID.PublicDocuments)
   if exception:
       print('bang! exception! do some error handling')
   else:
       print(documents_folder)
   ```

   (note this will probably fail on non-windows systems)

Comment: Many thanks.  I appreciate the third suggestion from this post: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2941#issuecomment-337076059.  Would you include this link.  I'd be happy to accept this answer.

Comment: @pylang No problem. I've edited the answer to include both a link the github issue, and a transcription of the content, just in case SO outlives GitHub (!)

Comment: FYI: I don't recommend menuinst anymore because it lagged in maintenance and updates on pypi, but at the time, this was a good answer.