# Edit the Jupyter terminal's starting directory

Tags: python, windows, terminal, jupyter

when I launch a Jupyter notebook (which I installed through Anaconda), the explorer opens in C:\Users\Joe

However, when I open a terminal (New -> Terminal) it opens in C:\Users\Joe\Documents

Is it possible to change the starting directory of the terminal, so it matches the notebook explorer page?

I have already tried the following:

1) edit the 'Start in' field in windows PowerShell properties to my desired location. This didn't change anything - it's as if when jupyter opens the terminal it overrides this - though it seems to use PowerShell.

2) running jupyter notebook –generate-config, and inserting my desired path to c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = "".

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Update - sorry, I've resolved this myself but don't think I can delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this myself - found the answer here:
[Find the default local Jupyter directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775023/find-the-default-local-jupyter-directory?rq=1)

In the Anconda3 folder there is a file cwp.py, which determines where the working directory should be changed to. I commented out lines 26-30:

```
if exception:
    documents_folder, exception = get_folder_path(FOLDERID.PublicDocuments)
if not exception:
    os.chdir(documents_folder)
```

and the path in the terminal is no longer being modified.