# How to navigate to a different directory in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: navigation, directory, jupyter-notebook

I have recently installed Anaconda 5 and with it Jupyter Notebook.  I am excited with its rich functionality but I can not find a way to navigate to directories which are not children.  More specifically I have tried to double-click the folder icon but that resulted in the same View.

[image]

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: This is the most annoying feature about python notebook.

Comment: @horaceT create a symbolic link to all other drives at your root directory. It works lika a magic.

Comment: @r.b.leon That'd be a pain in the ass. You never know which directory you want to read from/write to ahead of time.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Default root of the Jupyter explorer is the current location (directory) where you start the Jupyter server.
With the explorer, you can only navigate to all levels of the children directories, but not the parent's of that location.
There is an option to set the root directory `--notebook-dir` when you start Jupyter.
Here is an example command that starts Jupyter server and sets the root at `D:/my_works/jupyter_ipynbs`

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir D:/my_works/jupyter_ipynbs
```

Similarly, for `jupyter lab`:

```
jupyter lab --notebook-dir D:/my_works/jupyter_ipynbs
```

Once Jupyter is open on the web browser, its home or root directory will be what you specified as the value of `--notebook-dir`, in this case `D:/my_works/jupyter_ipynbs`. From that point, you can navigate to all its sub-directories.

Comment: "With the explorer, you can only navigate to all levels of the children folders, but not the parent's of that location". Why not? I mean, why the explorer doesn't allow to navigate freely over all folders in any direction? Can this behavior be changes somehow, e.g. in the configuration files? Thank you

Comment: @Confounded Please post your comment as a new question. In your question, you can refer to this answer. More people will see and give answer.

Comment: I think you need to add double quotes around the path for this to work!

Comment: @UpulieHan Not need them if the path has no `space`.

Answer (score 8):

For windows user there is another solution. You can create a symbolic link at directory that Jupyter starts working.

from command prompt: ( mklink /D [the name of the link] [target directory]

> mklink /D G_Drive G:\DsN20

Comment: Please explain your answer in a bit more detail with explanations. It is incomprehensible for a some of us, not well versed with computer jargon.  
\
What is a symbolic link?
Will the jupyter notebook still open with the original folder with a newly added option / shortcut to navigate to the linked folder?
Or will the jpnb be opened in the new folder only.
How will the name "G_Drive" be used for this purpose?

Comment: Let's assume Jupyter shows you the folders at C:/Users/[your username]. and you want to navigate and use files at another directory for example at D:\Test . all you need to do is  1- open command prompt by ( windows + r and type cmd and enter) .    2- navigate the directory that you are seeing at jupyter notebook home. 3- create a link by command mklink /D linkofgyaan D:\Test  4- ıt's done. now you can see it at Jupiter. Please check the following for more info: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/278262-mklink-create-use-links-windows.html

Comment: This works!! Thank you.  But you have to launch the command prompt with admin privileges, ie, search for cmd, right click, run as administrator.

Comment: @r.burak, thank you for sharing your solution. I have found this very helpful :)

Answer (score 7):

I use the next code to set jupyter lab from any root folder. From the Anaconda Prompt:

```
jupyter lab --notebook-dir "E:/Google Drive/Sediments_Regi"
```

Between the " " include the desire folder.

Answer (score 5):

On windows, when opening from command prompt, browse to the directory you wish

For example to browse to the directory D/pythonprograms

```
cd D:
cd pythonprograms
```

and execute

```
jupyter lab
```

this will start the instance with root folder as pythonprograms

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[This site](https://www.roelpeters.be/how-to-change-the-jupyter-notebook-default-directory/) describes 3 ways to start jupyter notebooks in specific folder:

1. By changing your current dir to the specific folder, then starting notebook from there:

cd C:\projects\notebooks
jupyter notebook

2. By using the **notebook-dir** parameter while staring notebook:

jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=C:\projects\notebooks\

3. By creating and editing the configuration file (permanent solution, for all environments): open your Anaconda prompt, run this command

jupyter notebook --generate-config

It will create file .jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py in C:\Users<your_user_name>. In this file, find c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir parameter, uncomment it by removing the hash and set the value to the directory of your projects.

c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'C:\projects\notebooks'

Now you can run Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda prompt (or the Anaconda Navigator), and you’ll start from your preferred directory. Keep in mind that you’ve changed the directory for every environment.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows: jupyter notebook "C:\ [route to any folder]"  ,also works even if the folder does not contain a jupyter notebook.  You can then navigate forward, but not backwards, to open or create a new notebook.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-the-jupyter-start-up-folder) post explains it very well for windows users

Answer (score 1):

I use Jupyter as plugin in my projects (`pipenv install jupyter`) and to make it start in current folder comment out `notebook_dir` option (or set to `''` — from Jupyter Notebook docs [Config file and command line options](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html)):

```
# ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

## The directory to use for notebooks and kernels.
# c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir
```

It is equivalent to writing every time `jupyter notebook  --notebook-dir .` (`.` — current folder)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, if you want a permanent change, the shortcut that is installed defaults to

> C:\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Anaconda3 C:\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py "%USERPROFILE%/"

If you change **"%USERPROFILE%/"** to **"C:\your\path"**, then opening the shortcut will go to the correct folder on startup.

note: I installed Anaconda to C:\Anaconda3, so yours might be a bit different based on where you installed it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution in my opinion:

- Open Notepad
- Paste the command `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10`
- Save the notepad file with an extension of `.bat` instead of `.txt`
- Paste the file in which directory you want to initialize your jupyter
- Double click and open the `.bat` file
- Jupyter opens with desired directory as base
- This way you control the jupyter root directory as and when required and don't
  really have to perform any manual settings

[`.bat` file created on Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nQvp.png)

[`.bat` file double clicked and executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMZbP.png)

[jupyter opens with Desktop as the intended base directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hSn4.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make a symbolic link in the default directory to '/'.  Then you can get to any file anywhere on the system without needing to know ahead of time which paths were of interest.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows PC, very simple. Open **anaconda prompt** and follow 2 steps:

1. Copy desired folder path, example: `C:\Rabiul\Folder_name`
2. Run `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir "C:\Rabiul\Folder_name"` in anaconda prompt.
   Path must be inside double quotations.

Here, it works fine with me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you open the jupyter notebook from the anaconda navigator, you will be able to move around in the directory structure as you please.

Comment: Please explain more, step by step to make your answer more usefull

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said, you can only navigate to children folders from the directory you started `jupyter` (or `jupyter lab`).

A quick hack to access notebooks outside the downstream folder tree is to add a symbolic link on the start jupyter folder:

```
> ln -s /path/to/desired/folder newfolder
```

Then you will see the `newfolder` name on the navigation bar of jupyter and you can access all the files within (no need to re-start jupyter server)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but I faced a similar issue operating jupyter notebook. My situation required me to open two .ipynb present in different folders, but whenever I tried launching two instances of jupyter notebook in their respective folders it only accessed the directory where the first command was run. The solution is very simple, just launch each jupyter notebook server on a different non-reserved port, i.e. 9999.

```
jupyter notebook --port 9999
```

Note: default port for the server is 8888 which is why the first folder is only opened despite executing the command in different folders.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way : Just type  `jupyter notebook` in the file explorer where ever to open jupyter notebook and press `Enter`
[image]

after couple of mins you will jupyter notebook page opening

[image]