# How to navigate to different directory in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I tried the answers in [How to navigate to a different directory in Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46755604/how-to-navigate-to-a-different-directory-in-jupyter-notebook), but they didn't work for various reasons:

Some answers are "how to permanently change your Jupyter start-up folder" which I don't want to do. I already did this, I set my start-up folder and I like it. Sometimes I just need to move around.

I tried changing my directory in Anaconda Prompt and launching lab, but it still takes me to my default start-up folder.

```
cd/d D:\Documents\my_new_folder
jupyter lab
```

Confirmed the cd worked.

On Windows.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you've navigated to the folder before running `jupyter lab`? If you type `pwd` (prints current directory you're in) in the terminal after navigating, does the correct path appear? For me the root path in Jupyter Lab is the path from where I executed `jupyter lab`. `cd/d` looks a bit strange, what if you change it to just `cd`

Comment: @Sandsten, yes confirmed. cd/d is to change from c drive to d drive

Comment: Then you might have set the default starting directory to be `C:/` or something similar. See if you have the following file `C:\Users\[USER]\.jupyter\jupyter_lab_config.py` and comment the line `c.ServerApp.notebook_dir = ''` and/or `c.ServerApp.root_dir = ''`. They might have been set to a path which will override the folder you run `jupyter lab in`

Comment: I've already set my default directory how I want it; on rare occasion, I need to go to a different folder

Comment: Then just run `jupyter lab --lab_dir="."` to override the default directory and start with the directory you're at now.

Comment: Sorry, should be `jupyter lab --notebook-dir="."`
Type `jupyter lab --help` to see all available commands to give

Comment: Glad it worker, wrote up an answer.

Comment: thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've set the default directory in the config file located at `C:\Users\[USER]\.jupyter\jupyter_lab_config.py`. You can use the option `--notebook-dir="."` to start Jupyter lab at the current folder you're in.

```
jupyter lab --notebook-dir="."
```