Can not find folder in jupyter notbook tree
I have installed Anaconda on my computer. I have Windows 11. I downloaded Anaconda directly from the respective website: Anaconda Download.
When I open a Jupyter Notebook, I get a tree view displayed at http://localhost:8890/tree from which I can choose, for example, http://localhost:8890/tree/Desktop, etc. I have a folder on my desktop with various .ipynb files. However, the entire folder is not displayed.
However, If I start Jupyter Notebook in the correct directory, i.e., from the folder where the files are located, it works. However, I can only view the contents of that folder. I can't navigate to other directories.
It’s as if the folder on the desktop does not exist. Do you know what the issue could be?

This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46755604/how-to-navigate-to-a-different-directory-in-jupyter-notebook/46762386#46762386
