Can't launch terminal in Jupyter Notebook on Windows
So, I can't open a terminal in Jupyter Notebook. I tried to reinstall Anaconda several times, but it did't work. Now I've installed Miniconda, but it's still the same. I have Windows 10, x64.
Here is the error:
[E 2024-04-21 21:11:33.756 ServerApp] Uncaught exception POST /api/terminals?1713723093741 (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='POST', uri='/api/terminals?1713723093741', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1784, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 3290, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\auth\decorator.py", line 65, in inner
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server_terminals\api_handlers.py", line 59, in post
        model = self.terminal_manager.create(**data)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server_terminals\terminalmanager.py", line 46, in create
        name, term = self.new_named_terminal(**kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\terminado\management.py", line 380, in new_named_terminal
        term = self.new_terminal(**kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\terminado\management.py", line 220, in new_terminal
        return PtyWithClients(argv, env, cwd)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\terminado\management.py", line 48, in __init__
        self.ptyproc = PtyProcessUnicode.spawn(**kwargs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'spawn'
[W 2024-04-21 21:11:33.760 TerminalsExtensionApp] wrote error: 'Unhandled error'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1784, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 3290, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\auth\decorator.py", line 65, in inner
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server_terminals\api_handlers.py", line 59, in post
        model = self.terminal_manager.create(**data)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server_terminals\terminalmanager.py", line 46, in create
        name, term = self.new_named_terminal(**kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\terminado\management.py", line 380, in new_named_terminal
        term = self.new_terminal(**kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\terminado\management.py", line 220, in new_terminal
        return PtyWithClients(argv, env, cwd)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\terminado\management.py", line 48, in __init__
        self.ptyproc = PtyProcessUnicode.spawn(**kwargs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'spawn'
[E 2024-04-21 21:11:33.760 TerminalsExtensionApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/tree",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
[E 2024-04-21 21:11:33.760 TerminalsExtensionApp] 500 POST /api/terminals?1713723093741 (f1c9f1e1a3464a4592c019f1c6a06ebb@::1) 6.88ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree```

How can I fix this? I haven't launched it for a long time, but it worked before and I didn't have any issues.

Did you set the PATH in system environment variable after installing Anaconda? If not, please follow steps mentioned here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318033/jupyter-notebook-will-not-open-from-command-prompt

The Jupyter itself is working fine. I can create new files, ipynb, etc. I just can't open a terminal inside Jupyter.
