# Error while importing a file while working with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, path, jupyter-notebook

Recently I've been working with `jupyter` notebooks and was trying to read an excel file with pandas and it gives me the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

But it works fine and reads the file with the exact same lines of code when i run it on `Spyder`.

Any advice on how to solve this issue?

Comment: try to specify a __full__ path to file...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an installation error,
Do this,

## For Python 2

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

## For Python 3

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

Comment: When I run it - the notebook through Anaconda it works fine. However, that issue only came when i ran Jupyter through the website - jupyter.org > Try it in your browser, and without having any software installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past. After having changed the Jupyter start folder as suggested in this post: [how to change jupyter start folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-jupyter-start-folder) , just put the excel file in this folder and to load them it isn't necessary to write the path. This is enough:

```
xl_file = pd.ExcelFile('myFile.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

Give full path while reading a file. It's running in spyder because the excel file and spyder are in the same folder while your jupyter is in a different folder. So it's not able to read the file.

```
df = pd.read_csv(full_path)
```

Comment: it's the full path I'm giving. I was working with jupyter notebook website when that happened. when i ran the notebook through anaconda it found the file with the same path I'm wondering why.