# Jupyter notebooks folder at startup

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

(Please read careful before marking this as duplicated)

In Windows 7 I installed Python 3 and Jupyter from Miniconda with `conda install jupyter`. The installation included a shortcut

[image]

which I find very useful because I even built one myself some time ago when I wasn't working with Miniconda but pure Python.

So, in Anaconda Prompt I did the well known `jupyter notebook --generate-config` to change the browser and set my notebooks root path.

[image]

The problem is that it still starts up from the user home directory even when it is actually taking the browser configuration I set. That means it is reading the config file but ignoring the notebooks directory setting.

[image]

I already tried the path with escaped backslashes and double quotes. I suspect it might be the parameters passed on in the shortcut, which I don't understand by the way.

[image]

Destination: `C:\Users\4217109\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\python.exe C:\Users\4217109\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\4217109\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3 C:\Users\4217109\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\python.exe C:\Users\4217109\AppDa`

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: have you tried launching it with `jupyter-notebook.exe --notebook-dir=C:\your\path`?

Comment: Actually `jupyter-notebook.exe` or `jupyter notebook` works as desired in Anaconda Prompt. In cmd shows an exception I think is related to the environment I used to install Python and Jupyter. So probably the parameters in the shortcut are overriding the directory setting only.

Comment: Figure out which environment you want to use (e.g., `C:\path\to\your\env\python.exe`) and then try putting the correct path in your shortcut, i.e., `C:\path\to\your\env\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe`

Comment: Setting the destination to `C:\Users\4217109\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe` raises the exception I mentioned. When I built my own shortcut I called `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k jupyter notebook && exit`. Is there a way to do the same with Anaconda prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing `c.NotebookApp.default_url` in ~config.py

---

### Details

You will be able to find " jupyter_notebook_config.py " file.

Please check this answer if you can't.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40514875/14180528

Then, find `c.NotebookApp.default_url` and change it for your purpose.
Example : `c.NotebookApp.default_url = /tree/Onedrive/Jupyter`