# I can't change Jupyter Notebook startup folder (limited "Target" field")

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook

I try to change Jupyter Notebook default folder. I used the official instruction that suggests I should change the shortcut: edit %USERPROFILE% to the full path of the new default folder, but I can't do this because field "Target" is limited. Also, I tried many different methods to solve the problem I've found here, but they don't work.
My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: I did it by creating a bat file with `@echo off;
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=C:\home\Library;  
pause`

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-the-jupyter-start-up-folder see the answer with the most upvotes, not the accepted one, though. You can create a user config file and change the directory there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the Jupyter start-up folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-the-jupyter-start-up-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Open jupyter.  Under "New" select terminal.  This opens a command prompt.  Type in cd "some path" where path is the file path.  For example I use an R drive so I type "cd R:" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuY2V.png)

Now you've changed the directory, type "jupyter notebook"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOxnz.png)