# How do I store files in a different working folder than jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've tried this before:`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-the-jupyter-start-up-folder`[image]

But when I changed the start-up folder, I found that the interface is blank. The packes and all that stuff were gone.[image]
These will disappear.

I want to create a shortcut under jupyter's working folder to a folder where I want to store my files, such as `d:\MLDemo`.
But here is a error:
[image]

What should I do about it?
Or is there another way to save files somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Windows 10:

1. Copy your path file location where you want to work

   Example: C:\Users\X\Desktop\JupyterWorkSpace
2. Create a shortcut of Jupyter notebook on your desktop
3. Right click on the shortcut; select properties;
4. Beside target, inside the path you will find: "%USERPROFILE%/"
5. Delete **%USERPROFILE%**
6. Paste your path file location inside **" /"**

   Example: "C:\Users\X\Desktop\JupyterWorkSpace/"
7. Apply and than click ok.