# Struggling to handle paths in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook

I'm struggling to handle my paths for the project. To give you an overview I need to show you my directory tree:

[image]

I'd like to setup the paths correctly so that I won't have to change them when working on two machines.

In PortfolioOptimizer notebook, I'm using:

```
# set current working path
notebook_path = os.getcwd()
print (notebook_path)
```

I don't understand, why it prints out *C:\xampp\htdocs\tools\python\learn2fly* which is the path to the different project.

Even when I add let's say portfolio_paths.py to Portfolio_analysis directory with this code:

```
import os


def get_dir_path():
    current_path = os.getcwd()
    return current_path
```

and then in my notebook I use the below line of code:

```
from Portfolio_analysis.portfolio_paths import get_dir_path
 # set current working path
notebook_path = get_dir_path()
```

I'm still getting *C:\xampp\htdocs\tools\python\learn2fly*

Answer (score 0):

`getcwd()` returns the current working directory, this may change based on the way you run Jupyter Notebook or Lab (namely if you use `--notebook-dir`).

Take also a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515095/5395497) answer.

Comment: Thank you! I think, I got it.