# How to change Jupyter start-up folder for different conda environments

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, startup

After seeing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40514875/12095613) on how to set the start-up folder for Jupyter Notebooks, I looked for how to do so for specific conda environments and haven't found an answer.

Is there a way to open up a Jupyter notebook in a location that is different depending on which conda environment within which you're activating it? I'm looking for a solution like the one above, where I could change `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/the/path/to/home/folder/'`, but in some environment-specific config file.

I guess an alternative would be to set some macro to activate the environment, `cd` to the desired folder location for this environment, then run `jupyter notebook` from that location.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate a DOSKEY macro to do the job. I combined [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040825/12095613) which shows how to set *persistent* aliases (macros) in command prompt, with [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/247551) which shows how to use multiple separate commands in a DOSKEY macro. As a summary here (mostly from Argyll's answer in the above persistent macro/DOSKEY post):

1. Create a file called something like `alias.cmd`
2. Insert the macro to automatically activate a conda environment, change file locations, and run a jupyter notebook from that location:

   - `doskey start_myEnv = conda activate myEnv $T cd C:\Users\user\path\to\my\notebooks\ $T jupyter notebook`
3. Run regedit and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`

   - or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` if not on Windows 10.
4. Add a String entry with the name `AutoRun` with the value set as the full path to the `alias.cmd` file.

Anytime you open the command prompt, executing start_myEnv will now activate myEnv, change to the folder that relates to that environment, and start a jupyter notebook.