# Change the starting folder of Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am having issues with changing the starting folder of Jupyter notebooks, as I would like to run the notebooks on a shared server. I am running Windows 10. I have already tried several of the options online:

- I have tried changing the "Start in" property of the jupyter
  shortcut: now the shortcut just quickly opens the terminal, then
  immediately closes again and nothing more happens.
- I have tried running the "jupyter notebook --generate-config"
  command, both in and outside python: in the first case it tells me
  that jupyter is not a recognised command, and in the second that
  there's a syntax error at notebook.
- I have made a .bat file with the instructions of the shortcut ('''C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe 
   C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\cwp.py 
   C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3 
   C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe 
   C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py 
   Z:\Test''') but it
  simply opens the terminal in python, and nothing more.

If I try to launch jupyter from the anaconda interface it works, and I can also start it from the terminal, but not in any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "jupyter notebook --generate-config" method, explained well in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40514875/12437754) from @marneylc, worked, I just had to start in the Anaconda Promt, rather than in cmd.

I hope this is the right way of answering my own question...