# How to change Users folders in jupyter notebook and jupyterlab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a question about jupyter notebook and jupyter lab and anaconda?

Does someone knows how to change the users folder from User a to b as an example?
I mean like I have 2 users in my PC and I want to use my secondary users folder in jupyter notebook and jupyterlab instead of my primary user folder.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom launching scripts for each user. The working directory can be set for jupyter lab using command line parameters:

```
jupyterlab --NotebookApp.notebook_dir=<directory_name>
```

(or using Jupyter config).

See related answer for the post: (How to change the Jupyter start-up folder)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515095/3247880]