# How to change Juypyter notebook default working directory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to change the default working directory for Jupyter notebooks (anaconda installation). I've looked up many different answers, most of which focus on changing the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file, but none of those work.

Some of the things i've tried:

- [This medium article](https://medium.com/@shanyitan/how-to-change-the-working-directory-of-jupyter-and-jupyter-lab-on-windows-environment-bbe5a5a99f05)
- [This github issue (bottom reply)](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/2665)
- [This](https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html#change-jupyter-notebook-startup-folder-windows)
- [This too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-the-jupyter-start-up-folder)

No matter what I try, whenever I start jupyter notebook the directory I see is `C:\Users\me`.

I admit part of the problem is that I'm not great with command line things which makes some of the answers difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the Jupyter Notebook from the Windows Start Menu then you have to change the command running Jupyter Notebook in the shortcut. Right click on the Start Menu on the shortcut, open file location, right click on the Jupyter Notebook shortcut, select Properties, and in the Terget Textbox, change the "%USERPROFILE%" part in what you wand or if you have changed the Jupyter config file, delete this part.