# How can I check if I installed Python, pandas, and Jupyter with conda or pip? Should I reinstall it with conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I don't remember how I installed python. I'm learning to use Jupyter now and the official website recommends to install python using conda, not pip.

1) Why is installing python and Jupyter with pip not advisable? I understand the [difference between pip and conda](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-conda-and-pip), but can someone please explain to me why Jupyter recommends to use conda to install it? Is there a way for me to check how I installed python? Should i reinstall it with conda if I used pip?

2) I'm trying to understand the whole conda is a package installer but also manages venv. typed "list" into the anaconda prompt and it gave me a list that I have some questions about.

```
(base) C:\Users\ellie>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\ellie\anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
anaconda                  2020.02                  py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0
appdirs                   1.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
argh                      0.26.2                   py37_0
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0
astroid                   2.3.3                    py37_0
astropy                   4.0              py37he774522_0
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0
autopep8                  1.4.4                      py_0
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
backports                 1.0                        py_2
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
bcrypt                    3.1.7            py37he774522_0
beautifulsoup4            4.8.2                    py37_0
bitarray                  1.2.1            py37he774522_0
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0
blosc                     1.16.3               h7bd577a_0
bokeh                     1.4.0                    py37_0
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0
bottleneck                1.3.2            py37h2a96729_0
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0
cffi                      1.14.0           py37h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003
click                     7.0                      py37_0
cloudpickle               1.3.0                      py_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0
comtypes                  1.1.7                    py37_0
conda                     4.8.2                    py37_0
conda-build               3.18.11                  py37_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h62dcd97_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0
cryptography              2.8              py37h7a1dbc1_0
curl                      7.68.0               h2a8f88b_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
cython                    0.29.15          py37ha925a31_0
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py37he774522_0
dask                      2.11.0                     py_0
dask-core                 2.11.0                     py_0
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
diff-match-patch          20181111                   py_0
distlib                   0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
distributed               2.11.0                   py37_0
docutils                  0.16                     py37_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37he774522_0
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0
flake8                    3.7.9                    py37_0
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
fsspec                    0.6.2                      py_0
future                    0.18.2                   py37_0
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    1.4.0            py37he774522_0
glob2                     0.7                        py_0
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37hfa6e2cd_0
h5py                      2.10.0           py37h5e291fa_0
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0
hypothesis                5.5.4                      py_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
imageio                   2.6.1                    py37_0
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0
importlib_metadata        1.5.0                    py37_0
intel-openmp              2020.0                      166
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_0
ipykernel                 5.1.4            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.12.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0
jedi                      0.14.1                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.11.1                     py_0
joblib                    0.14.1                     py_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
json5                     0.9.1                      py_0
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0
jupyterlab                1.2.6              pyhf63ae98_0
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0
keyring                   21.1.0                   py37_0
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37ha925a31_0
krb5                      1.17.1               hc04afaa_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37he774522_0
libarchive                3.3.3                h0643e63_5
libcurl                   7.68.0               h2a8f88b_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
liblief                   0.9.0                ha925a31_2
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h33f27b4_0
libssh2                   1.8.2                h7a1dbc1_0
libtiff                   4.1.0                h56a325e_0
libxml2                   2.9.9                h464c3ec_0
libxslt                   1.1.33               h579f668_0
llvmlite                  0.31.0           py37ha925a31_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1
lxml                      4.5.0            py37h1350720_0
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h2fa13f4_0
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37he774522_0
matplotlib                3.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
menuinst                  1.4.16           py37he774522_0
mistune                   0.8.4            py37he774522_0
mkl                       2020.0                      166
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37h675688f_0
mock                      4.0.1                      py_0
more-itertools            8.2.0                      py_0
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37h74a9793_1
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0
nbformat                  5.0.4                      py_0
networkx                  2.4                        py_0
nltk                      3.4.5                    py37_0
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2
notebook                  6.0.3                    py37_0
numba                     0.48.0           py37h47e9c7a_0
numexpr                   2.7.1            py37h25d0782_0
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h93ca92e_0
numpy-base                1.18.1           py37hc3f5095_1
numpydoc                  0.9.2                      py_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openpyxl                  3.0.3                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1d               he774522_4
packaging                 20.1                       py_0
pandas                    1.0.1            py37h47e9c7a_0
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
paramiko                  2.7.1                      py_0
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0
path                      13.1.0                   py37_0
path.py                   12.4.0                        0
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_0
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py37_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pillow                    7.0.0            py37hcc1f983_0
pip                       20.0.2                   py37_1
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0
ply                       3.11                     py37_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.3                      py_0
psutil                    5.6.7            py37he774522_0
py                        1.8.1                      py_0
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37ha925a31_2
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37he774522_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37hfa6e2cd_9
pycurl                    7.43.0.5         py37h7a1dbc1_0
pydocstyle                4.0.1                      py_0
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0
pygments                  2.5.2                      py_0
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pylint                    2.4.4                    py37_0
pynacl                    1.3.0            py37h62dcd97_0
pyodbc                    4.0.30           py37ha925a31_0
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.4.6                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py37_1
pyrsistent                0.15.7           py37he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0
pytables                  3.6.1            py37h1da0976_0
pytest                    5.3.5                    py37_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0
pytest-astropy            0.8.0                      py_0
pytest-astropy-header     0.1.2                      py_0
pytest-doctestplus        0.5.0                      py_0
pytest-openfiles          0.4.0                      py_0
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py37_0
python                    3.7.6                h60c2a47_2
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.4                      py_0
python-language-server    0.31.7                   py37_0
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0
pywavelets                1.1.1            py37he774522_0
pywin32                   227              py37he774522_1
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py37_1000
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py37_0
pyyaml                    5.3              py37he774522_0
pyzmq                     18.1.1           py37ha925a31_0
qdarkstyle                2.8                        py_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 0.6.1                      py_0
qtconsole                 4.6.0                      py_1
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_1
rope                      0.16.0                     py_0
rtree                     0.9.3            py37h21ff451_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37he774522_0
scikit-image              0.16.2           py37h47e9c7a_0
scikit-learn              0.22.1           py37h6288b17_0
scipy                     1.4.1            py37h9439919_0
seaborn                   0.10.0                     py_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                45.2.0                   py37_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.14.0                   py37_0
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0
soupsieve                 1.9.5                    py37_0
sphinx                    2.4.0                      py_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.0                      py_0
spyder                    4.0.1                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            1.8.1                    py37_0
sqlalchemy                1.3.13           py37he774522_0
sqlite                    3.31.1               he774522_0
statsmodels               0.11.0           py37he774522_0
sympy                     1.5.1                    py37_0
tbb                       2020.0               h74a9793_0
tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0
terminado                 0.8.3                    py37_0
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
tk                        8.6.8                hfa6e2cd_0
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0
tornado                   6.0.3            py37he774522_3
tqdm                      4.42.1                     py_0
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0
twilio                    6.39.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ujson                     1.35             py37hfa6e2cd_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0
urllib3                   1.25.8                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
virtualenv                20.0.16                  pypi_0    pypi
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1
watchdog                  0.10.2                   py37_0
wcwidth                   0.1.8                      py_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
werkzeug                  1.0.0                      py_0
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xlsxwriter                1.2.7                      py_0
xlwings                   0.17.1                   py37_0
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0
xmltodict                 0.12.0                     py_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
yapf                      0.28.0                     py_0
zeromq                    4.3.1                h33f27b4_3
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0
zipp                      2.2.0                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0

(base) C:\Users\ellie>
```

2.1) does this show me a list of all my packages or just the packages i installed with conda?

2.2) according to conda.io, "Conda channels are the locations where packages are stored". What is a "pypi" location? How is that a location? Also, it says at the top that everything is stored at `C:\Users\ellie\anaconda3:`. So how is a channel different from the `C:\Users\ellie\anaconda3:` lcoation?

3) Is there a downside to moving the default jupyter notebook location to somewhere other than the C drive? / Is anyone else's jupyter home directory (`http://localhost:8888/tree`) filled with garbage like a desktop folder and some shit you installed 80 years ago? None of the tutorial people have their entire lives in their tree directory, so this makes me wonder where I went wrong. I'm sorry that this is the dumbest question ever. Is there a reason Jupyter made a folder with a bunch of garbage in it my home directory? Is there a downside to moving my home directory to the D drive?

Answer (score 2):

## 1)

Installing Anaconda encompasses python and the conda package manager. Anaconda is a tool, or framework, containing very many useful tools and programs to work with (big) data.

I believe the reason Jupyter wants you to use conda, is to make sure the dependencies are already installed, and the fact that it is mainly developed for the Anaconda environment.

Speaking of venv, the reason it is installed is that Anaconda also functions as a environment manager, letting you choose your installed packages and versions. For example, you could create an environment which uses python2, and install only python2 libraries in it, without changing the root environment.

If you used pip to install python, i recommend just installing Anaconda as a whole.
Jupyter without Anaconda is also feasible, but does not nearly have the same amount of support and frameworks, and fiddling with the jupyter-libs is not something that pays off (trust me, I tried myself).

The bottom line is that pip gives you more freedom in what you want to install, but conda is easier to use and recommended for data-driven programming. They can co-exist without a problem (except maybe some problems with your path, which should be really easy to fix, judging by the amount of questions about this topic on StackOverflow.).

I personally use Jupyter strictly with Anaconda, because it lets me switch between projects on-the-fly without worrying about having the right dependencies available, and it lets me use JupyterHub, which is a big plus in my book. Also, it spares me the hassle of fiddling with the jupyter versions, which can be a real pain.

## 2.1)

These are all packages that either were shipped with conda, or you yourself installed with conda. However, if you want to be sure, you can check your pip packages by running `pip list`. Your pip packages should be stored somewhere else on your machine, so your python installs do not get in each other's way. Thankfully, this is the default.

## 2.2)

Channels are NOT a location on your drive, they are locations on the conda cloud. If conda looks for a package to install, it iterates through a hierarchy of channels, until it finds your requested package or finds nothing on any channel. You can to some extent
[control this hierarchy](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/manage-channels/), but as a beginner it is not important. The channels that are important, however, are those that are given by your operating system; if you use Windows, only packages are found that are explicitly availiable for the Windows operating systems. These packages, in turn, are organized in a channel, mostly named after your os. These packages are then installed on your drive in a folder with the same name as the channel, so conda can keep track of the different packages you have installed for different os's.

## 2.3)

It is possible (and recommended) that you start your Jupyter Notebook in the respective folder, either by using `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir '<your folder>'` or by [changing the jupyter start folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-the-jupyter-start-up-folder).

On a sidenote, most of the questions you asked here are already answered on this site, and with a little digging you could have answered most of these questions beforehand.

Nevertheless, i am not a Anaconda pro myself, and channels are a concept that somebody else might elaborate on some more.