# How to access directories outside the working directory of jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I know how to set a working directory or initial directory of Jupyter.

[How to change the Jupyter start-up folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-the-jupyter-start-up-folder)

However, when I do such, I don't have access to the parent directory of the working directory. I want to set the root directory of Jupyter to home directory to have access to all directories, but I want to have my specific directory (e.g. `my notebooks`) as the initial directory that the file browser shows initially, so if I wanted I could go up and browse other directories...

Comment: If you want to specific directory to be your default directory, then open your jupyter notebook in the specific directory using `jupyter notebook`

Comment: @bigbounty I wrote that in my question too, but I want two things. To have an initial directory and also a root directory which aren't the same necessarily

Comment: Differentiate "initial" and "root" giving some example

Comment: By "root" I mean the scope of my access (if Jupyter wants to restrict it, for example `/home/aa/bb`), but I don't want the file browser starts at it every time, I may want to intially goes to `/home/aa/bb/cc` instead I go to `cc` manually

Answer (score 1):

From my jupyter notebook, I start in the following working directory:

```
import os
os.getcwd()

'C:\\Users\\...\\my_working_dir'
```

Suppose I want to access the file 'abc.py' in another directory.

I can use this command directly in my jupyter notebook:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'G:/your_path_where_abc_is/')
from abc import ColumnSelector
os.getcwd() # unnecessary: just to show that the working directory is the same as before

'C:\\Users\\...\\my_working_dir'
```

So that I can load it from another directory without changing my working directory.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: directly in your jupyter notebook

Comment: I do but nothing changes (I mean the browser screen is still in the same working directory)

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your question correctly: this was a way to access files in other directories.

Comment: you said and `from there I can load files for example`... could you extend your answer to say how you load a file for example?

Comment: Thanks, it might be helpful for loading files or modules... but I meant to have access them in file broweser so that I can load them in browser and run them....