# how to change default start-up folder jupyter hub on Azure DSVM virtual machine

Tags: azure, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, azure-dsvm

Azure DSVM has jupyterlab enabled on port 8000.
However, the startup folder in jupyterlab always starts at /home/*user-name/notbook.
I want to change the jupyterlab start folder, but I don't know what to do.

## tried

### 1.

I created a jupyterlab configuration by referring to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-the-jupyter-start-up-folder) to change `c.NotebookApp.notbook_dir`, but rebooted and checked again for server operation. I've confirmed it's not working.

### 2.

I also tried to create a jupyterhub configuration, but it came out that there was no command called jupyterhub.
I thought it was working in docker, but there was no process for jupyterhub in docker.

### 3.

netstat -tnlp

```sh
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44675         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46277         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2048/python         
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

ps aux | grep jupyter

```sh
root      1345  0.0  0.0  13316  3304 ?        Ss   00:06   0:00 /bin/bash /etc/jupyterhub/start_jupyterhub.sh
root      1624  0.0  0.0 246340 64268 ?        Sl   00:06   0:01 /anaconda/bin/python /anaconda/bin/jupyterhub --log-file=/var/log/jupyterhub.log
root      1949  0.0  0.0 606436 51356 ?        Ssl  00:06   0:01 node /usr/local/bin/configurable-http-proxy --ip * --port 8000 --api-ip 127.0.0.1 --api-port 8001 --error-target http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/error --ssl-key /etc/jupyterhub/srv/server.key --ssl-cert /etc/jupyterhub/srv/server.crt
rootadm+  2048  0.2  0.0 343804 101160 ?       Ssl  00:07   0:03 /anaconda/bin/python /anaconda/bin/jupyterhub-singleuser --port=46277 --notebook-dir=~/notebooks --SingleUserNotebookApp.default_url=/lab --config=/etc/jupyterhub/default_jupyter_config.py
rootadm+  3841  0.0  0.0  14864  1040 pts/0    S+   00:27   0:00 grep --color=auto jupyter
```

Comment: If you are running JupyterLab 3.x then you should ber using `c.ServerApp.root_dir` instead of `c.NotebookApp.notbook_dir`.

Comment: I looked for the config file, but there is no 'c.NotebookApp.notbook_dir'.(jupyter lab version : 3.0.16)@krassowski

Comment: And there should not be. Please re-read my comment which is saying that you should use `c.ServerApp.root_dir`.