# How to change default save location in Jupyterlab (Anaconda)?

Tags: python, anaconda, save, jupyter-lab

[This folder is still the C folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rleq.png)

Hello y'all,

I've uninstalled the entire Anaconda distribution on the C drive and reinstalled it on the D drive. However, when I launch Jupyterlab in Anaconda, the default save location is still the C drive, and auto saves the scripts in there. How can I change the save location (in picture) to D drive, where the Anaconda package is installed?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does it solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35254852/15239951?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder location C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\.jupyter and open the file named, jupyter_notebook_config.py in any text editor.
Everything in this config file will be commented on file creation. Search for the key string, #c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir
Uncomment the key string by deleting the # sign and in single quotes type the location of your custom startup folder and save the changes. Use forward slashes instead of backward slashes in the folder path. As an example, C:/jupyter_workspace

I hope it will help

Comment: Please, [edit] your answer instead of comment.

Comment: Hello Maxim, thank you for your help! But it didn't work for me, unfortunately. The file jupyter_notebook_config.py couldn't be found - maybe because I use JupyterLab and not the notebook... I tried to search through the USER folder for a similar file but no luck. Thanks anyways!