# Python Syntax Error (Unicode error)

Tags: python-3.x

[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg04E.jpg)

I am trying to convert a CSV to XLS using Python 3.5.1 I have attached a picture to show the issue

```
import csv, xlwt

files = ["C:\Users\Office\Documents"]

for i in files:
f=open(i, 'rb')
g = csv.reader ((f), delimiter=";")
wbk= xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

for rowi, row in enumerate(g):
    for coli, value in enumerate(row):
        sheet.write(rowi,coli,value)

wbk.save(i + '.xls')
```

Comment: Google + (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file (that is, search the first little part of the error message).

Answer (score 2):

Following [@KoebmandSTO's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906530/python-syntax-error-unicode-error#comment59473494_35906530) you may want to [try this](https://www.google.com/#q=(unicode+error)+%27unicodeescape%27).

you are using backslashes in the string that are normally used to escape special characters like `\n`, to prevent this behaviour use `r"..."`:

```
files = [r"C:\Users\Office\Documents"]
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l) for better explanation on what the `r` does.

or backslash escape the backslash with `\\`:

```
files = ["C:\\Users\\Office\\Documents"]
```

since the `\` is a special character that needs to be escaped.