# Image Python tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, label

The below code on running, gives the following error, Please help me resolve it

### Code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

path='C:\Users\Sabyasachi\Pictures\Formal Reception.jpg'



  root = tk.Tk()
   img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
        panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
        root.mainloop()
```

ERROR:'unicodeescape' codex cant decode bytes in position

Comment: This post would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file

Comment: Hey @user128285, this does solve the issue but then I get an error, 'No module named PIL', how do I solve that?

Comment: What version of python do you have?

Comment: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how exactly you defined your path (or is that just bad formatting?). You have to escape the backslashes and spaces: `path='C:\\Users\\Sabyasachi\\Pictures\\Formal\ Reception.jpg'`

Or use a raw string `path=r'C:\Users\Sabyasachi\Pictures\Formal Reception.jpg'`

Comment: forward slashes is also an option. `path=C:/Users/...`

Comment: Hey @Bryan, this does solve the issue but then I get an error, 'No module named PIL', how do I solve that

Comment: @SabyasachiPatra; you have to install it. Google can help you there, because it depends if you're in venv (the une pip) or just basic install as described here: http://wp.stolaf.edu/it/installing-pil-pillow-cimage-on-windows-and-mac/.