# How to avoid txt copy with folder creation for each user

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying create folder:

```
import os

mypath = (r'C:\my_folder')
if not os.path.isdir(mypath):
   os.makedirs(mypath)
```

I've got error from windows or if this way `mypath = (r'C:\ProgramData\my_folder')`
 I got this error:

```
mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\my_folder'
```

so as script does not have permissions to write, now with help from previous post here

[PermissionError: [WinError 5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955921/permissionerror-winerror-5)

I must use this rule:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/

this way:

```
import os

mypath = os.path.join(os.getenv('programdata'), 'my_folder)
if not os.path.isdir(mypath):
    os.makedirs(mypath)
```

and I got folder here:

> C:\ProgramData\my_folder

Works, but new problem, for example as it was before: `mypath = (r'D:\my_folder\)` this way I have folder and when I start program first time, this creates textdoc.txt inside, works perfect, but if I go this way `mypath = os.path.join(os.getenv('programdata'), 'my_folder)` If with first one I have one textdoc.txt, now I have two: textdoc without extension and second textdoc.txt. Well it's ok if just copy, but it completely spoiled a data work, specific lines are recorded in one file other parameters in textdoc without extension. I checked several times all access to the database, no errors in the code and it does not happens with local working path `mypath = (r'D:\my_folder')`

**EDIT:**

I'm just missed something in my code, not associated with the method itself

so working one:

Same answer that is given here: [PermissionError: [WinError 5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955921/permissionerror-winerror-5?lq=1)

```
import os

mypath = os.path.join(os.getenv('programdata'), 'my_folder')

if not os.path.isdir(mypath):
    os.makedirs(mypath)
```

and path for document:

> C:\ProgramData\my_folder\document.txt

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't create a textdoc or do anything with it. I suspect the problem is in your code after the directories are created.

Comment: yes text file created after, but as I've said  it does not happens if I have location outside  system files for example with  mypath = (r'D:\my_folder')