# unicode error when import matplotlib using Anaconda

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am making a GUI using tkinter and i am using matplotlib to print some graphics in a tk windown. But when i run the code it gives me a "unicode error".

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzl9y.png)

I already know that the problem is with the "\U" part in the paths, but i can't find a way to change this and remove the error.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @Vinicius-Syl, please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the directory string.

```
"C:\Users\Vinicius"
```

Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347854/),

"Here, \U starts an eight-character Unicode escape, such as '\U00014321`. In your code, the escape is followed by the character 's', which is invalid.

You either need to duplicate all backslashes, or prefix the string with r (to produce a raw string)." @martin-v-löwis

Comment: Note that in Python 2, `\U` escapes are still processed even in raw (unicode) strings, so you must duplicate the backslashes in front of the Us.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. So... i know that I need to do this, the question is: since this is an automatic import from the module, and it already knows the path to look for, how can I change that?

Comment: Use a raw string r'path', double \\, or forward /  instead.