# Cannot launch exec in subprocess with path

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to launch an executable from python subprocess and I have a problem with the path.
I'm trying to run newman.cmd which is located in

```
C:\Users\<myself>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I try

```
subprocess.run("C:\Users\<myself>AppData\Roaming\npm\newman.cmd run","shell=True")
```

which fails, indicating:

```
Syntax Error: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape: C:\knxnet\test_differentiel.py, line 71, pos 23
subprocess.run("C:\Users\<myself>\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman.cmd run","shell=True")
```

If I copy newman.cmd and the appropriate folders in my local path, I end up launching the command as expected, ie. this works:

```
subprocess.run("newman.cmd -h")
```

I checked the path and it gives me the following:

```
ENV =  <irrelevant info> ;C:\Users\<myself>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

so I though it would find it ? how can I do to avoid copying executables in my current directory ?

thanks for any help ...

Comment: Is there any chance that your username contains non-ASCII characters?

Comment: I found the problem ... it's the U of Users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out the answer thanks to SO ... ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

It is interpreted as unicode followed by an unwanted character ... the position indicated in the error was the quote's position, so I didn't catch the hint. 
so I tried with r:

```
subprocess.run(r"C:\Users\a.joly\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman.cmd -h")
```

and it works. It also works if I double the "\".

thanks for your time ...