# Decompiling Pyinstaller

Tags: python, obfuscation, pyinstaller, decompiling

I am trying to decompile an executable through pyinstaller [extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyinstallerextractor/).

I have decompile pyinstaller exe as image shows https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3r2X.jpg . I cannot seem to get it to work.
I'm getting `""" SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 841-842: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.`

I tried changing path.  Any ideas?
I have tried changing the syntac using `\\` and incorporating that but I have had no luck. I am happy to provide a video tutorial as evidence if needed but this is not the same question as it did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

Comment: @AKhudairy Thanks, that was first thing I tried.  Should have mentioned that.  Did not help.