# i am trying to json.load() a json file but getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Code**

```
import json
file_name = "storing and reading JSON\user_number.json"
with open(file_name) as j_obj:
    num = json.load(j_obj)
    print("I know your favorite number, it's: " + str(num))
```

**Error**

> error detail: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 24-25: truncated \uXXXX escape

Comment: try file_name = "storing and reading JSON\\user_number.json"

Comment: wow, it worked, thanks buddy, but what is the logic behind it, how to get rid of these unicode errors? is there a source to learn this logic?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have accidently written an escape character in your file directory:

```
file_name = "storing and reading JSON\user_number.json"
```

Notice after `storing and reading JSON` you have `\u`? Python is interpreting it as an escape character and as a result it cannot load your JSON file.

The right way to write the directory would be to cancel out the escape sequence by writing a double backslash `\\`:

```
  file_name = "storing and reading JSON\\user_number.json"
```

For more information about [escape characters](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Comment: Please don't forget to "accept answer" to an answer that worked to solve your issue.