# error while using pandas to open a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\VIJAY\Desktop\coursera_AI")
```

When I use pandas in Python to open a `csv` file it's showing

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Can someone help me to figure out the error please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file. Basically, try `C:\\Users\\VIJAY\\Desktop\\coursera_AI`

Comment: For the code data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\VIJAY\\Desktop\\for_correlation.csv"). Im getting this error:    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 26: invalid start byte. Whats wrong with this code