# Tensorflow Audio Recognition - Training Data

Tags: python, tensorflow, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I want to test out Tensorflow's audio recognition by training my own set of data. Following the instructions from the Tensorflow Simple Audio Recognition Tutorial:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition

I receive an error when I run the train.py:
SyntaxErorr:  'unicodescape' codec can't decode byes in position 2-3...

I changed the `--data_dir=/your/data/folder/` to a folder in my computer with my own set of data by like this in the train script:

```
parser.add_argument(
  '--data_dir',
  type=str,
  default='C:\Users\Matthew Chen\Documents\GSF\ALL',
  help="""\
  Where to download the speech training data to.
  """)
```

where ALL is the folder with all of my WAV files.

I assume that I have not disabled `--data_url=` correctly but the documentation does not seem to provide enough detail onto how to disable it.

This is what the `--data_url=`  looks like:

```
parser.add_argument(
  '--data_url',
  type=str,
  pylint: disable=line-too-long
  #default='C:\Users\Matthew Chen\Documents\GSF\...\ALL',
  # pylint: enable=line-too-long
  help='Location of speech training data archive on the web.')
```

Is it possible that I have to input a specific string to disable it?

Comment: have a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file

Comment: `python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py \  `                                `--data_url= \ `                                                                                                                                           `--data_dir=/your/data/folder \ `                                                                                     `--summaries_dir=/your/dir \   `                                                                                          `--wanted_words=left,right,up,down`