# Error when using of glob to open various files in a folder

Tags: python, glob

I have a simple Question, I'm using the following Code to open multiple files in Python but it doesn't work, it just gives me one error.

**Error:**

> "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
>   in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape "

```
for name in glob.glob('C:\Users\lpa\namefolder1\namefolder2\namefolder3/*'):
```

Comment: Use a raw string: `r'C:\Users\lpa\namefolder1\namefolder2\namefolder3/*'`

Comment: It says "invalid Syntax"

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file) Do refer this post.

Comment: @lpng Did you put the `r` in front to turn your string into a raw string? I get errors without it, but none with it...