# how to open csv in python?

Tags: python, csv, import, data-analysis

I have a dataset in following format.

> row_num;locale;day_of_week;hour_of_day;agent_id;entry_page;path_id_set;traffic_type;session_durantion;hits
>       "988681;L6;Monday;17;1;2111;""31672;0"";6;7037;\N"
>       "988680;L2;Thursday;22;10;2113;""31965;0"";2;49;14"
>       "988679;L4;Saturday;21;2;2100;""0;78464"";1;1892;14"
>       "988678;L3;Saturday;19;8;2113;51462;6;0;1;\N"

I want it to be in following format :

> row_num   locale   day_of_week  hour_of_day   agent_id   entry_page path_id_set   traffic_type   session_durantion   hits
>       988681 L6 Monday     17 1  2111 31672   0       6 7037  N
>       988680 L2 Thursday   22 10 2113 31965   0       2 49   14
>       988679 L4 Saturday   21 2  2100 0      78464    1 1892 14
>       988678 L3 Saturday   19 8  2113 51462   6       0  1    N

I tried with the following code :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Rahhy\Desktop\trivago.csv", delimiter = ";")
```

But I am getting a error as :

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: The path looks fishy.

Comment: @DirtyBit Meaning ??

Comment: Okay, you edited it now.

Comment: @pistol2myhead I tried those solutions earlier given in the link you have shared. None of them worked so I posted my query.

Comment: @RahulKumar The error arises because you didn't escape the backslashes in the path. The solutions in the linked question fix this. Please use one of them, run the code again and post the new error message.

Comment: Your real problem is not the `delimiter` but the multiple chars that you need to get rid of.

Comment: the link for the original datasets


https://zealpath-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/cases/Build%20a%20predictive%20%27hits%27%20model%20%28Copy%29-428/ML_Data_Scientist_Case_Study_Data.zip?Signature=wFl1S51c7auTogQvrwRDMuAW9dk%3D&Expires=1554992389&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJTXGMWYZOKXO4LZA

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `replace()`:

```
with open("data_test.csv", "r") as fileObj:
    contents = fileObj.read().replace(';',' ').replace('\\', '').replace('"', '')
print(contents)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
row_num locale day_of_week hour_of_day agent_id entry_page path_id_set traffic_type session_durantion hits
988681 L6 Monday 17 1 2111 31672 0 6 7037 N 988680 L2 Thursday 22 10 2113 31965 0 2 49 14 988679 L4 Saturday 21 2 2100 0 78464 1 1892 14 988678 L3 Saturday 19 8 2113 51462 6 0 1 N
```

**EDIT**:

You can open a file, read its content, replace the unwanted chars. write the new contents to the file and then read it through `pd.read_csv`:

```
with open("data_test.csv", "r") as fileObj:
    contents = fileObj.read().replace(';',' ').replace('\\', '').replace('"', '')
# print(contents)

with open("data_test.csv", "w+") as fileObj2:
    fileObj2.write(contents)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"data_test.csv", index_col=False)
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
row_num locale day_of_week hour_of_day agent_id entry_page path_id_set traffic_type session_durantion hits
988681 L6 Monday 17 1 2111 31672 0 6 7037 N 988680 L2 Thursday 22 10 2113 31965 0 2 49 14 988679 L4 Saturday 21 2 2100 0 78464 1 1892 14 988678 L3 Saturday 19 8 2113 51462 6 0 1 N
```

Comment: With pandas , Cant it be imported ?? I want to do some data analysis on it.

Comment: @RahulKumar sure, adding it in a moment.

Comment: Yes, this works but the no. of variables are 10 and corresponding values are 11... how to deal with it ??

Comment: @RahulKumar Indeed, works fine. Do you get any errors?

Comment: NO Errors in execution of above codes but when I try to retrieve a column say `df["hits"]` it is throwing error `KeyError: 'hits'`

Comment: Use `index_col=False` to not use the first data field for indexing (see my answer or https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @DirtyBit since you've replaced all semicolons with whitespaces `read_csv` need's the `delimiter=' '` to parse the csv correctly. (See rejected edit).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Load the file to a string (prefix r (raw) to not use \ for escaping)
filename = r'c:\temp\x.csv'
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    raw_file_content = file.read()

# Remove the quotes which break the CSV file
file_content_without_quotes = raw_file_content.replace('"','')

# Simulate a file with the corrected CSV content
simulated_file = StringIO(file_content_without_quotes)

# Get the CSV as a table with pandas
# Since the first field in each data row shall not be used for indexing we need to set index_col=False
csv_data = pd.read_csv(simulated_file, delimiter = ';', index_col=False)
print(csv_data['hits']) # print some column
csv_data
```

Since there are 11 data fields and 10 headers only the first 10 fields are used. You'll have to figure out what you want to do with the last one (Values: \N, 14)

Output:

```
0    7037
1      49
2    1892
3       1
```

[image]

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(simulated_file, delimiter = ';', index_col=False)` works fine but when i type `df["hits"]` it gives this error `KeyError: 'hits'`

Comment: I'm getting the correct output with `df['hits']`. What development environment are you using? Have you made sure to overwrite `df` with the result of my script after running DirtyBit's answer?

Comment: Maybe time to check the data you actually read: `print(csv_data)` or `print(csv_data.columns.values)` (these are the column names and it should contain 'hits')

Comment: I m on python3.7 and window 10 with spyder ide. Whenever trying to print a column `hits` throwing error `keyerror : 'hits'`

Comment: `print(csv_data.columns.values)` retrives 
`['row_num locale day_of_week hour_of_day agent_id entry_page path_id_set traffic_type session_durantion hits']`

I think python here is retriving all separate columns as single column

Comment: Yes result for `csv['row_num locale day_of_week hour_of_day agent_id entry_page path_id_set traffic_type session_durantion hits']` is whole table while csv_data['hits'] is error  `Keyerror : hits `.... How to proceed now ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your file is no longer the original one since you ran DirtyBit's script and replaced it's contents. So the `;` is no longer the separator. Try changing the delimiter to ` `(space) or reset the file to it's original content.