# joining strings together to make a unicode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit

I am trying to create a random unicode generator and made a function that can create 16bit unicode charaters. This is my code:

```
import random
import string

def rand_unicode():
    list = []

    list.append(str(random.randint(0,1)))
    for i in range(0,3):
        if random.randint(0,1):
             list.append(string.ascii_letters[random.randint(0, \
             len(string.ascii_letters))-1].upper())
        else: 
            list.append(str(random.randint(0,9)))

    return ''.join(list)


print(rand_unicode())
```

The problem is that whenever I try to add a '\u' in the print statement, Python gives me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

I tried raw strings but that only gives me output like '\u0070' without turning it into a unicode character. How can I properly connect the strings to create a unicode character? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

Comment: I saw that one, but it is nearly a decade old with a much older version of python, and the answers there only partially answered this problem. Also, I am using a mac.

Comment: tried the 'u' flag? maybe find something helpful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: \u0070 is a single character, just like \n is a single character. Concatenation \u with 0070 does not mean what you think it means. Creating the escape sequence literal to create a character is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

From:

> The problem is that whenever I try to add a '\u' in the print statement, Python gives me the following error:

it sounds like the problem may be in code you haven't included in your question:

```
print('\u' + rand_unicode())
```

This won't do what you expect, because the `'\u'` is interpreted before the strings are concatenated. See [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python) and try:

```
print(bytes('\\u' + rand_unicode(), 'us-ascii').decode('unicode_escape'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A unicode escape sequence such as `\u0070` is a single character. It is not the concatenation of `\u` and the ordinal.

```
>>> '\u0070' == 'p'
True
>>> '\u0070' == (r'\u' + '0070')
False
```

To convert an ordinal to a unicode character, you can pass the *numerical* ordinal to the [`chr` builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr). Use `int(literal, 16)` to convert a hex-literal ordinal to a numerical one:

```
>>> ordinal = '0070'
>>> chr(int(ordinal, 16))  # convert literal to number to unicode
'p'
>>> chr(int(rand_unicode(), 16))
'ᚈ'
```

Note that creating a literal ordinal is not required. You can directly create the numerical ordinal:

```
>>> chr(112)  # convert decimal number to unicode
'p'
>>> chr(0x0070)  # convert hexadecimal number to unicode
'p'
>>> chr(random.randint(0, 0x10FFF))
'嚟'
```