# Opening a GIF picture with PIL in Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to open a GIF file but it is coming up with a syntax error i do not understand. Does the image have to change to PNG / JPEG because i am trying to keep transparency which would be lost if i have to change the file type.

[The Syntax Error i don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHrFS.png)

I have tried to keep the image and open it with Turtle by using screen.addshape. That works for the image however i have had a problem with resizing the image so i am having to use the PIL library to open the images and then resize them

Comment: Please, do not post errors as screenshots. Take the minute it needs to copy the message and type it here so other users might find your question (and perhaps a solution) based on the error message.

Answer (score 1):

`Image.open("your.gif")` should work. However, the path is not the string you think it is. `\` is the escape character. To type a `\`, you will need to use `\\` in stead of `\`.

Thus `Image.open("C:\Your\Path\to a funny\image.gif")` 
becomes 
`Image.open("C:\\Your\\Path\\to a funny\\image.gif")` or `Image.open(r"C:\Your\Path\to a funny\image.gif")` (a raw string).

Answer (score 0):

Its String encoding of the file path which is causing the issue
See:
["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

Comment: It opens in Photos instead of in a python file, is there a way to make it so it opens in the actual python screen? For example to get the image to move locations on python screen.