# Error while reading an excel file using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read an Excel file to a pandas dataframe. The code is as bellow:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
df = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\user\Desktop\ConsumersData_English.xlsx')
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escapeter code here
```

Using previous answers of similar questions, I tried to put 'r', forward slash, double backslash - but nothing worked. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that the `\U` is seen as an escape sequence. You should use a raw string, or use an operating system that works with forward slashes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `\U` is seen as an escape sequence. You should use a *raw string*, escape the backslashes manually, or use an operating system that works with forward slashes.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\ConsumersData_English.xlsx')
```

Comment: I work in jupyter notebook and new to python, can you elaborate more on how to do it manually. @Willem Van Onsem. Thanks!

Comment: @Ariel, surely too late to help you, but for others who may be similarly confused, notice that there is an "r" just before the string containing the file spec. That r tells python to treat the string as a raw string, that is, not to interpret the backslash as a special character.