# how to i read a text file save in my computer with python

Tags: python

I created a text file with name `important` on windows and stored the file in documents but when I try to access the file with the command `open('important')` I get the following traceback message:

```
C:\Users\donad trump\Documents\python4me\train>python.exe test4.py 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "test4.py", line 1, in <module> file = open('important') 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'important'
```

My code is:

```
file = input('important')
reat = file.read()
print(reat)
```

Comment: give the full path then

Comment: Your Windows may be set to automatically hide known file extensions. If you used something like Notepad to create your text file, its name is not what you think.

Comment: C:\Users\donad trump\Documents\python4me\train>python.exe test4.py
  File "test4.py", line 1
    file = input('C:\Users\donad trump\Documents\important.txt')
                 ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

C:\Users\donad trump\Documents\python4me\train>
i still get this error message, thanks !! i still need your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honest opinion, from your code, my guess is that you are a beginner with Python (totally fine!) and you have not checked any kind of available help. It is ok to be a beginner, everyone was. But you should take the time to read how to open files in Python in the many (many, many, many...) available sources.

This is a good one:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp

But surely, you can find many others by just googling "read file Python 3".

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```py
with open("path/to/important.txt", "r") as file:
     trump_should_wear_a_mask = file.read()
```