# how to import csv to jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I can't import a csv file onto the jupyter notebook i've tried all the solutions on the site prefixing the dir with r, using backslashes, forward slashes and double backslashes. what do i do?
this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\sidha\main.csv")
```

Comment: try giving the complete path. Something like `C:\Users\sidha\main.csv`. What error are you getting?

Comment: File "<ipython-input-18-cc189f8291d6>", line 2
    df = pd.read_csv(":\Users\sidha\main.csv")
                    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Try to check you are giving the file path correctly without any letters mistakes.

Comment: sorry i messed up the question but i did give the complete path:

Comment: You could try with "\\" instead of "r": `df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\sidha\\main.csv")` -- Never mind, saw you already tried.

Comment: have u checked this thread?:https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347854/11045279

Comment: Have you tried putting the *.csv directly in the root of your project (same folder from where you started the jupyter notebook) and passing just the name of it? Something like `df=pd.read_csv("news.csv")` should work easier.