# Can't add image in python, pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So i get this error

```
image = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\spaceship.png")
                          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I did it with the exact path, and just with files name, but i still can't add it.

Comment: You have to escape the backslashes. That means replacing \ with \\ in your string should solve the problem

Comment: try this `pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/spaceship.png")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

Comment: Before asking a new question it's always best to search for already existing Q/As on Stack Overflow and on other online resources. For example, if you search Stack Overflow with your error message you'll find similar (and already answered) questions immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `\` in strings is used for special chars like `\n` (break).

You can solve this either in this way:

```
image = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\spaceship.png")
```

or this way:

```
image = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\spaceship.png")
```