# "Unicode error "when trying to connect to microsoft SQL server 19

Tags: sql-server, django, database, windows

I am trying to use the Microsoft SQL server as my database of django project but when I am trying to connect it it give me a `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 9-10: truncated \uXXXX escape` . The issue is with `'USER': 'INDIANLEO\user',`.

Here is the database connection

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'ENR',
        'HOST': 'INDIANLEO',
        'USER': 'INDIANLEO\user',
        'PASSWORD': '',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the server name and details:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“Unicode Error ”unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes… Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1347791/2029983)

Comment: Side note, when using a trusted connection, you don't pass the username and password though; so the user and password options shouldn't even be there (and thus the error will disappear and there won't be a unicode escape codec).

Comment: It now shows incorrect password or id

Comment: See my second [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66101720/unicode-error-when-trying-to-connect-to-microsoft-sql-server-19#comment116867218_66101720).

Comment: should it be blank?

Comment: To quote myself... *"so the user and password options **shouldn't even be there**"*

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the backslash in your username. Python interprets `\u` as a special character instead of `\` then `u`.

You should provide a raw string `r"INDIANLEO\user"` or double backslashes `INDIANLEO\\user`.

Any way, you should use a trusted connection so that the connection uses the process security context to authenticate, so that you wouldn't need to provide the credentials yourself.