# I can't play sound on python program, I get this error

Tags: python

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I wrote this code :

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('C:\Users\City Computer\Music\New folder\\play.mp3')
```

Comment: there is a problem with your path passed to the function. as a simple backslash is an escape character in python

Comment: i also have tried double slashes in but it still give me this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

Here, `\U` in the path `'C:\Users...` starts an eight-character Unicode escape, such as `\U00014321.` In your code, the escape is followed by the character 's', which is invalid. (As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347854/16496244))

#### Solutions:

There are three ways to solve this issue

**1.** Duplicate all backslashes (basically escape the escape character)

```py
'C:\\Users\\City Computer\\Music\\New folder\\play.mp3'
```

**2.** Prefix the string with r (to produce a raw string)

```py
r'C:\Users\City Computer\Music\New folder\play.mp3'
```

**3.** Use forward slashes(/) to avoid confusion

```py
'C:/Users/City Computer/Music/New folder/play.mp3'
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. But you have mentioned a link to another post on SO. It means that the question is duplicate. You should flag it as a duplicate

Comment: The reason I didn't flag it as duplicate is that the link I provided didn't included the 3rd solution. If I should have still flagged it as duplicated, then I apologize for my ignorance.