# I have a "Syntax" Error in python while trying to load the file

Tags: python, import

```
red_voznje = []
def otvori_redvoznje(prevoznik,odrediste,peron,rezervacija,termin):
    datoteka = open("red_voznje.csv","r",encoding="utf-8")   
    for line in datoteka:
        vrednosti = line.rstrip().rsplit(",")
        recnik = {
                "prevoznik": vrednosti[0],
                "odrediste": int(vrednosti[1]),
                "peron": int(vrednosti[2]),
                "rezervacija": vrednosti[3],
                "termin": int(vrednosti[4])
            }
        red_voznje.append(recnik)

    return red_voznje
```

Here is the error i get:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

Comment: Thanks for this it has removed the error but now doesnt load the file at all.

Answer (score 0):

could avoid unicode error with `errors = 'ignore'` in open()

eg     datoteka = open("red_voznje.csv","r",encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")

Comment: Thanks,But its still giving the same error even after i added that.

Comment: could switch to read binary 'rb' instead of read text 'rt' to get a byte literal

Comment: I cant change to binary because the assignment must stay in csv format.

Comment: it is still string so once you have the byte literal can just take off the "b' " at the start and the " ' "  at the end before your csv retrieval/workings. To check what the byte literal looks like can print(datoteka)

Comment: Thanks for the help i will try it.

Comment: But i think that the error is more in the syntax of the code then in the open section.

Comment: yeah sorry -  meant print(datoteka.read())

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Formatted files have headers and sometimes footers with info for apps that use the file. Need to research csv format to find out what position in file data is at. These files are usually in binary which can get unicode errors since Python encoding seems to be problematic with these (to me anyway). Can use <file>.seek(<position>) and data size if necessary and str(<data read>) for text .  Wikipedia often has good info about different file formats.