# add r' to a python variable

Tags: python, pandas

```
#create filepath for log files for the specific region
region_log_filepath = join(log_files_folder_path, region)

#files stores file paths
files = [join(region_log_filepath, file) for file in listdir(region_log_filepath) if isfile(join(region_log_filepath, file))]

for file in files :
           if file.endswith('csv'):
               filename = (file.split('Log-')[-1]).split('.csv')[0]
               print(f'\nreading file: {filename}')
               log_file = pd.read_csv(file,encoding='unicode_escape')
```

The above code gives the error : ***UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 26850-26851: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape***

I tried looking it up and found a post suggesting to convert it to a raw string. How would I add r' to file in the pd.read_csv() function ?

Comment: There are many encodings to choose from: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings but I don't know what format your file is actually in. Maybe try 'utf_8' instead of 'unicode_escape'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file

Comment: @qrsngky They are CSV files

Answer (score 0):

You can pass encoding parameter in `read_csv()` method according to the format of the file,

you can try using one of these,

```
"utf-8",
"ISO-8859-1", 
"latin",
"cp1252"
```

Syntax: `read_csv(file, encoding = "utf-8")`

Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings for more.

Comment: when I add utf-8 I get this error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 15: invalid start byte

Comment: It is because the date is not encoded in `utf-8`. Try using `encoding="cp1252"`

Comment: when I add cp1252 I get this error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 22: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: please go through the link given in my solution at the end, there are lots of encoding standard, which standard to be used depends on the data, you will be able to find the appropriate standard as per your data format using that link.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried looking it up and found a post suggesting to convert it to a raw string. How would I add r' to file in the pd.read_csv() function ?

Then you only need to use 'utf-8' encoding in read_csv. It will ignore those Unicode-like sequences and treat it like the characters they are.

Comment: when I add utf-8 I get this error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 15: invalid start byte

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).