# Can't do ASCII with 'u' character in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to do an ascii image in python but gives me this error

```
File "main.py", line 1
    teste = print('''
                  ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 375-376: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

And I think it's because of the U character, why that happened, is any way to solve this?
[ASCII image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbGV7.png)

Comment: Post text not images of text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `\U` in your string, which is being interpreted as the beginning of a Unicode ordinal escape (it expects it to be followed by 8 hex characters representing a single Unicode ordinal).

You could double the escape, making it `\\U`, but that would make it harder to see the image in the code itself. The simplest approach is to make it [a raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/364696) that ignores all escapes save escapes applied to the quote character, by putting an `r` immediately before the literal:

```
teste = print(r'''
```

Note the `r` immediately after the `(`, before the `'''`.