# Pandas/to_csv, it show Error-- unicodeescape codec can't decode bytes

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

when I use pandas `to_csv`, it show Error , how to handle it ? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
    dataframe.to_csv('D:\working\GTM\us.csv',encoding='utf-8')
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 14-15: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Comment: The problem is with the string Check this answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347854/14966387

Comment: Use raw string for path

Comment: Either raw string or double backslashes like `'D:\\working\\GTM\\us.csv'`

Comment: Or `'D:/working/GTM/us.csv'`