# How do I read/write to a .adofai file using strings?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read from and write to a .adofai file (which from what I can tell is a modified .json which won't work with the json library) using strings.

This is the program I used for testing:

```py
import re
with open("C:\Users\\user\Downloads\pythontime\mirror.adofai", "r") as f: #open and read from file, store data in s
    print(f.read)
    s = f.read()

s = re.sub("\"angleData\": \[0", "\"angleData\": [315", s) #replace 0 with 315

with open("C:\Users\\user\Downloads\pythontime\mirror.adofai", "w") as f: #open and write modified string to file
    f.write(s)
```

mirror.adofai before modification:

```json
{
    "angleData": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    "settings":
    {
        "version": 12 ,
        "artist": "", 
        "specialArtistType": "None", 
        "artistPermission": "", 
        "song": "", 
        "author": "", 
        "separateCountdownTime": "Enabled", 
        "previewImage": "", 
        "previewIcon": "", 
        "previewIconColor": "003f52", 
        "previewSongStart": 0, 
        "previewSongDuration": 10, 
        "seizureWarning": "Disabled", 
        "levelDesc": "", 
        "levelTags": "", 
        "artistLinks": "", 
        "difficulty": 1, 
        "requiredMods": [],
        "songFilename": "", 
        "bpm": 100, 
        "volume": 100, 
        "offset": 0, 
        "pitch": 100, 
        "hitsound": "Kick", 
        "hitsoundVolume": 100, 
        "countdownTicks": 4,
        "trackColorType": "Single", 
        "trackColor": "debb7b", 
        "secondaryTrackColor": "ffffff", 
        "trackColorAnimDuration": 2, 
        "trackColorPulse": "None", 
        "trackPulseLength": 10, 
        "trackStyle": "Standard", 
        "trackGlowIntensity": 100, 
        "trackAnimation": "None", 
        "beatsAhead": 3, 
        "trackDisappearAnimation": "None", 
        "beatsBehind": 4,
        "backgroundColor": "000000", 
        "showDefaultBGIfNoImage": "Enabled", 
        "bgImage": "", 
        "bgImageColor": "ffffff", 
        "parallax": [100, 100], 
        "bgDisplayMode": "FitToScreen", 
        "lockRot": "Disabled", 
        "loopBG": "Disabled", 
        "unscaledSize": 100,
        "relativeTo": "Player", 
        "position": [0, 0], 
        "rotation": 0, 
        "zoom": 100, 
        "pulseOnFloor": "Enabled", 
        "startCamLowVFX": "Disabled",
        "bgVideo": "", 
        "loopVideo": "Disabled", 
        "vidOffset": 0, 
        "floorIconOutlines": "Disabled", 
        "stickToFloors": "Enabled", 
        "planetEase": "Linear", 
        "planetEaseParts": 1, 
        "planetEasePartBehavior": "Mirror", 
        "customClass": "",
        "legacyFlash": false ,
        "legacyCamRelativeTo": false ,
        "legacySpriteTiles": false 
    },
    "actions":
    [
    ],
    "decorations":
    [
    ]
}
```

The program is supposed to replace the first 0 in `angleData` with a 315, but it gives the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\user> & C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/user/Downloads/pythontime/mirror.py
  File "c:\Users\user\Downloads\pythontime\mirror.py", line 2
    with open("C:\Users\\user\Downloads\pythontime\mirror.adofai", "r") as f:
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

(Note that I've replaced my username with `user` here for privacy reasons.)

Comment: Maybe dublicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file). Answer maybe this r"C:\Users\\user\Downloads\pythontime\mirror.adofai"

Comment: that was a mistake on my part while editing the question, my username started with a character that necessitated the double slash, but I didn't replace the double slash with a single one after I changed it to `user`.

Comment: anyway, the answer on the question worked, thank you for linking it!